# How do I get a button to become disabled only when a table view has 0 rows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsbutton

I have two buttons - 'Insert row' and 'Delete row', created through interface builder.

When there are 0 rows in my table, I want the 'delete row' button to be greyed out.

I'm told that the way to disable a button is - [button setEnabled:no] or by unticking the 'Enabled' box in interface builder. However, either of these cases will not work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Create an IBOutlet for your button in your .h file as

```
AppDelegate.h


{
    IBOutlet NSButton* yourButton;
}
```

Then ctrl+drag from your button in xib to FileOwner/AppDelegate and connect the referencing outlet of button to yourButton in AppDelegate class.

Now, if your are populating the table view using data source methods, implement

```
AppDelegate.m

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;
{
    if(![yourArray count])
    {
        [yourButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [yourButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
    return [yourArray count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that [button setEnabled:NO] doesn't disable the button? You need to set a different visual style for its disabled state to have it look disabled. Try testing if the button is enabled by tapping on it.

Comment: I don't really know how to call the method setEnabled for the 'delete row' button specifically, because I created it through IB. Is there a way of finding out the object name of that particular button so that I can use this 'setEnabled' method?

Comment: Seems like you didn't create a reference to the button in your controller from IB.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You Should set UIButtonType and UIButton setTitle for default greyed out. For example programme should be like

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [button setTitle:@"delete row" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.enabled = NO;
 button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
```

And If you set background image for UIButton. You need to set your custom UIImage for enable and disable.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enable.png"] 
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disable.png"] 
                  forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the bindings of your button then follow the below bindings.
 For that you need to bind the button to Enable property - >   Array Controller -> Selection - >
       Model Keypath -> "@count"

Comment: If this also does not solve then the NSTableView also needs to be bound. Binding its Selection Indexes to the Array Controller.selectionIndexes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have bindings to an array controller. Then you can bind the enabled property of the delete button to the canRemove property of the array controller.

Answer (score 0):

if you are populating your table view through binding, here is the snippet you can try

```
if(![[arrayController arrangedObjects] count])
        {
            [button setEnabled:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [button setEnabled:NO];
        }
```

where arraycontroller is outlet of NSArrayconrtoller which content array in XIB.